# Remove countries from JSON file

Tags: qgis, geojson, json, topojson, remove

I have [this file nuts0.jso](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s6st_zQG_U0hn91tXCf3i48rYcFEK4EH)n that I would like to change by removing some countries like Iceland.
To do this, I used the method I found in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267961/remove-some-islands-from-europe-json-file). Then I coverted the GeoJSON file to TopoJSON using [mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org/).

It works but the countries that have the islands (such as France, Italy, UK, etc.) are divided.

Let me explain better, when I do a visualization using the original file and move the mouse over Italy, I get this:

[image]

When I do the same thing using the modified file with QGIS, I get this:

[image]

These are the files:

- original file: [nuts0.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s6st_zQG_U0hn91tXCf3i48rYcFEK4EH)
- modified file: [nuts03.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UELr1W0tZCWU0XgH0y-EPQ9MlsNIbdTV)

As you can see, here are the two pieces of code that are different:

**nuts0.json**:

```
{
    "arcs": [[[81, 82, -63, -24, -4]], [[83]], [[84]]],
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "properties": {
        "nuts_id": "IT",
        "name": "Italy",
        "population": 59685227
    },
    "id": "IT"
}
```

**nuts03.json**:

```
{
    "arcs": [[66, 67, -53, -19, -4]],
    "type": "Polygon",
    "properties": {
        "id": "IT",
        "nuts_id": "IT",
        "name": "Italy",
        "population": 59685227
    }
}, {
    "arcs": [[68]],
    "type": "Polygon",
    "properties": {
        "id": "IT",
        "nuts_id": "IT",
        "name": "Italy",
        "population": 59685227
    }
}, {
    "arcs": [[69]],
    "type": "Polygon",
    "properties": {
        "id": "IT",
        "nuts_id": "IT",
        "name": "Italy",
        "population": 59685227
    }
}
```

How can I solve?

Comment: In QGIS, go to `Vector | Geometry Tools | Singleparts to multipart`. Select `id` (or `nuts_id`) as **Unique ID field**.

Comment: you should add this as an answer @Kazuhito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modified layer `nuts03.json` has Italy as a set of three parts. Each part is represented as a separate record in the attribute table. This is so-called `Single parts`.

[image]

`Singleparts to Multipart` tool can put them into one collection of features (`Multi part` geometry).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the use the *Delete Part* function from the *Advanced Digitizing Toolbar* to manually delete only parts of countries which have multiple separate polygons.

Probably you have to activate the toolbar first under View > Toolbar > Advanced Digitizing Toolbar. After enable editing for your layer, you can choose the function *Delete Part* which is highlighted in the following screenshot:

[image]

Now simply select all areas you want to delete and save the file when you are finished. Now all original multipart objects stay intact and the highlighting works as expected.